# Convetion of relation table with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity

I read the Entity Framework Core documentation on how to customize one-to-many relationship and I don't understand the difference between this convention. You can see these convention here [1].

So what it's the difference between these conventions ?

```
[1]:https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx
```

I tried only the conventions 1 and 2.

Convention 1:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
}
```

Convention 2:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Convention 1 doesn't work.  There is no unique ID to map the Student Class with the Grade class.  Convention 2 is really no good since you cannot get a grade from a student.  You can only get a student from the grades.  You really need a common property to link the tables.  In convention 2 it would be better to have the StudentId instead of the list of Students.

Comment: Yes but this would be a one to one relationship and with Entity Framework I can't build my foreign key like you said with StudentId.

Comment: You can only have a foreign key if the property is in both tables.  You need to add the StudentId to the grade table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you access the `Grade` property through the `Student` entity to see a student's grade. In the second example you would access the `Students` property through the `Grade` entity to see all students with that grade. You can actually do both and in each instance you can define the relationship specifically using the fluent API or relevant attributes.

Comment: So there are no major differences between the two conventions ?

Comment: It depends if you want to access the grade from the student or the student from the grade. If you want to do both you will require additional fields. Personally I normally use what they describe as convention 4 and make all the properties accessible.